# Check anchor tags color

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have anchor tags as follows:

```
<a href="link1.html" class="none_standard_links">link one</a><br />
<a href="link2.html" class="none_standard_links">link two</a><br />
<a href="link3.html" class="none_standard_links">link three</a><br />
<a href="link4.html" class="none_standard_links">link four</a><br />
<a href="link5.html" class="none_standard_links">link five</a><br />
<a href="link6.html" class="none_standard_links">link six</a><br />
<a href="link7.html" class="none_standard_links">link seven</a><br />
<a href="link8.html" class="none_standard_links">link eight</a><br />
<a href="link9.html" class="none_standard_links">link nine</a><br />
<a href="link10.html" class="none_standard_links">link ten</a><br />
```

How do I loop through the entire set and alert the url of the link if it has a style sheet color of red?

I have tried making a start with the script, but don't know how to finish off:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button1').click(function() {
        $(".none_standard_links").each(function (i) {
            if (this.style.color = "red") {
                alert("not sure what to do here?");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If the approach I am attempting is not the best way to go about doing this, please feel free to make changes.

Comment: What is changing the colour of your links? Can you just check for a class on them or something? And are you wanting to check colour changes due to the link haveing been already visited or active, and so on?

Comment: Regardless of whether you're doing it the wrong or right way, you're missing an "=". `if (this.style.color == "red") {`

Comment: FYI, this won't work in a few months, most if not all the browsers are introducing a privacy layer that prevents javascript from determining if a link has been visited based on it's styling.

Comment: @Spencer Hakim:  So is it better to add a small image next to the active link, then use javascript to detect which link has the small image to find out which link is currectly active?

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. You won't be able to detect the :active styles at all, no matter what you do. That's the point, you shouldn't be able to do what you're trying to do, since it's a very blatant violation of privacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working as follows:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $(".none_standard_links").each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).css("color") == "red") {
            alert($(this).attr("href"));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's better to cache your jQuery selectors. Ie. `var $this = $(this);` and then use `$this` throughout the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

`if (this.style.color == "red")` Will never work coz it's reading inline style, not style applied from stylesheets.

May I ask what are you trying to achieve here? Aren't stylesheets designed by you, and you should know the color?

The only thing I can think of that you wanna do is to detect a visited link. In that case, `a:visited { padding: 10px 0 }` with `$('a')[0].offsetHeight` should do it.

Comment: I remember in modern browser there is a property called `computedStyle`, but I am not sure how to access it though.

Comment: Basically, I want a way to know which link in a list of link is currently active.

Comment: `active` as in the cursor is currently over it? You should use `mouse*` events.

Comment: active as in which link is clicked and is currently being displayed.

Comment: You mean the link with a URL of the current page? You could simply probe `$('a').attr('href')` for that.